# Одновременное создание нескольких TCP-подключений

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tcp-ip, сеть, .net

Нужно создать сканер портов по открытому IP. Есть рабочий вариант, но в нем подключение происходит последовательно, по порядку. Требование преподавателя - создавать одновременно несколько подключений, например, блоками по 100. В C# еще не слишком разбираюсь, потому как сделать - не совсем представляю.

Comment: раскидайте подключения по отдельным потокам. О работе с потоками можете почитать [эту статью][1]

[1]:http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Вам нужно распараллелить работу вашей программы. Читайте про [потоки в C#](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml/)

Comment: @DreamChild не обязательно создавать отдельные потоки для асинхронной работы с несколькими подключениями.

Comment: @AlexeyM, эм?

Comment: @Veikedo, по крайней мере в \*nix можно сделать сокет неблокируемым (тогда connect вернет управление сразу) и потом использовать select (или его аналоги) для отслеживания событий с сокетами.